# How to draw the matlab plot to match features in a single image?

Tags: image, matlab

I have been working on checking duplicated regions in an image. I used SURF to describe the key-points followed by measuring the Euclidean distance and getting two sets of features that could indicate possible duplicated regions.

I am trying to modify [**this**](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/showmatchedfeatures.html#btq_ljs) code to apply it to a single image but I haven't had any need for the matchFeatures function there since I was working on a single image. So I haven't got any indexPairs variable on which the plot is dependent. Is there any way to obtain this variable?

If that's not possible, it would be fine if I could draw a line between two sets of SURF features on the image represented by two m x n arrays.

The (b) and (d) images [**here**](http://www.lambertoballan.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/abcds_icassp10.png) are the type of results I'm trying to obtain.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole process in your case is the same as [**this**](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/showmatchedfeatures.html#btq_ljs). if you have got the coordinates of regions in your image, you just need to crop those regions and use them as I2 as [**this**](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/showmatchedfeatures.html#btq_ljs) ( I1 is the reference region in your image that you should firstly crop it). On the other hand, if you don't have coordinates of the regions you can randomly select x and y coordinates in the image and then evaluate them step by step in a loop. For instance, if the source image is given as 
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yajTq.png) 
then we can find similar candidates to the template by this:

```
%% Step 1: Read Images
clc;clear all;close all;
template_coordinate=[27.5 55.5 269 268];
sample_coordinates=[406.5 48.5 269 268];
templateImage = imcrop(imread('german.png'),template_coordinate);
templateImage=rgb2gray(templateImage);
for i=1:size(sample_coordinates,1)
    sampleImage = imcrop(imread('german.png'),sample_coordinates(i,:));
    sampleImage=rgb2gray(sampleImage);
    %% Step 2: Detect Feature Points
    % Detect feature points in both images.
    templatePoints = detectSURFFeatures(templateImage);
    samplePoints = detectSURFFeatures(sampleImage);
    %% Step 3: Extract Feature Descriptors
    % Extract feature descriptors at the interest points in both images.
    [boxFeatures, templatePoints] = extractFeatures(templateImage, templatePoints);
    [sceneFeatures, samplePoints] = extractFeatures(sampleImage, samplePoints);
    %% Step 4: Find Putative Point Matches
    % Match the features using their descriptors.
    boxPairs = matchFeatures(boxFeatures, sceneFeatures);
    %% Step 4: Make decision of similarity
    % This can be done by counting the number of the  size(boxPairs,1) or other metrics
    %% Step 5: display pair points
    matchedBoxPoints = templatePoints(boxPairs(:, 1), :);
    matchedScenePoints = samplePoints(boxPairs(:, 2), :);
    figure;imshow(imread('german.png'))
    hold on
    for n=1:size(matchedBoxPoints.Location,1)
        point1=round(matchedBoxPoints.Location(n,:))+template_coordinate(1:2);
        point2=round(matchedScenePoints.Location(n,:))+sample_coordinates(1:2);
        xy = [point1;point2];
        % plot([point1(2),point2(2)],[point1(1),point2(1)],'Color','b','LineWidth',2)
        plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
        plot(point1(1),point1(2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
        plot(point2(1),point2(2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
    end 
end
```

and obtain the output like [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Nxv.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. I have the coordinates but I don't understand how to plot them in a single image. Is there any matlab function that takes one image and displays the features or is there any way to modify the "plot" function to do that?

Comment: Honesty, I don't know any function that directly plots these points. I added an example to make the proposed method more clear. Pay heed, that this method for evaluating similar regions isn't such an appropriate solution due to time consuming. Maybe you should better to check template matching with correlation filter